# "С волками жить - по-волчьи выть" - каков изначальный смысл пословицы?

Tags: значения, пословицы

Каков изначальный смысл пословицы "С волками жить - по-волчьи выть"? Я смотрю на разные источники в Интернете и замечаю, что они предлагают разные толкования заложенного в эту пословицу смысла.

Есть источники, которые считают, что эта пословица несет *рекомендательный* смысл: если ты хочешь жить с волками, то лучше *старайся* вести себя по-волчьи. В частности, пословица часто сопоставляется с выраженно рекомендательной английской "When in Rome, do as the Romans do."

Я лично всегда воспринимал смысл этой пословицы по-другому, как констатацию *объективной неизбежности*: будешь жить с волками - *хочешь-не хочешь*, но сам рано или поздно обязательно превратишься в волка. Есть источники, поддерживающие и эту точку зрения.

Как правильно заметил @Victor Bazarov в комментариях, наличествует еще и третий вариант интерпретации этой пословицы, основанный на использовании слова "выть" в значении "страдать": будешь жить с волками - завоешь, хлебнешь горя.

Так каков же канонический смысл этой пословицы? Откуда она пошла?

Comment: Много лет назад, как мне помнится, её использовали как раз во втором смысле - неизбежность изменений в поведении под влиянием окружения.  Возможен и третий вариант, что жизнь в волчьей стае настолько *тяжёлая*, что (не захочешь а) *взвоешь*.

Comment: Я тоже склоняюсь ко второму значению, и на правильность такого толкования указывает инфинитив несовершенного вида. Согласно М. Безяевой, коммуникативный смысл несовершенного вида - неизбежность. И такой же смысл - неотвратимость, абсолютная команда - несёт инфинитив (ср. например, обращение: Сядь! и Сидеть! ).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Коннотация неизбежности в этой пословице совершенно точно есть. На самом деле "с волками жить - по волчьи выть", как это нередко бывает с подобного рода высказываниями - это всего лишь один из вариантов - самый известный, но были и другие, например:

- Либо с волками выть, либо съедену быть.
- Так и быть: с волками выть ([встречаем](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dahl_proverbs/14186/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA) у Даля)

Да, и, кстати, эта пословица упомянута у Даля в разделе "Воля-Неволя"

Так что да, это не совсем про то, что нужно следовать каким-то правилам социума, а скорее про то, что если даже этот социум плох, придётся сосуществовать по его правилам.